# Difference between f(x::Real) and f{T <: Real}(x::T)?

Tags: types, julia

Is there any difference between defining functions with `f(x::Real)` and `f{T <: Real}(x::T)`?

`@code_warntype` gives the same output for

```
function f(x::Real)
    x^2
end

function g{T <: Real}(x::T)
    x^2
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *parametric type* `T` isn't actually used to express any relationships between types, so there's little justification for its usage, which just adds needless complexity.

Here's an example, in which using a parametric type would be necessary:

```
function pow{T <: Real}(base::T, exponent::T)
    base^power
end
```

In this case, `T` is necessary to enforce that both `base` and `exponent` have the same type, with the restriction that that type must be a subtype of `Real`.

In constrast, here's the same function, without using a parametric type:

```
function pow(base:: Real, exponent:: Real)
    base^power
end
```

Now this functions requires that both `base` and `exponent` be subtypes of `Real`, but there's no type relationship that enforces that both be of the same subtype of `Real`.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer `f(x::Real)`. Extra unnecessary type parameters make things harder for the compiler and slower for dynamic dispatch, not to mention harder to read for other humans.

See the [style guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/style-guide/#Don%27t-use-unnecessary-static-parameters-1):

> ### Don’t use unnecessary static parameters
>
> A function signature:
>
> ```
> foo{T<:Real}(x::T) = ...
> ```
>
> should be written as:
>
> ```
> foo(x::Real) = ...
> ```
>
> instead, especially if T is not used in the function body. Even if T is used, it can be replaced with typeof(x) if convenient. There is no performance difference. Note that this is not a general caution against static parameters, just against uses where they are not needed.
>
> Note also that container types, specifically may need type parameters in function calls. See the FAQ Avoid fields with abstract containers for more information.

Comment: Hey, what about `foo{x::T, y::T}(x::T, y::T)` vs `foo(x::T, y::T) where {x::T, y::T}`. Whats the preferred style? is `foo{x::T, y::T}(x::T, y::T)` being deprecated in 0.6?

Comment: Do you mean `foo{T}(x::T, y::T)`? If you have 0.6, prefer `foo(x::T, y::T) where {T}`.